# R: How can I create rows based on the values of other rows?

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a data frame:

```
 df <- data.frame(
  comp_name = c("A","A","B","B","A","A","B","B","C","C","D","D","C","C","D","D"),
  country = c("US","US","US","US","US","US","US","US","France","France","France","France","France","France","France","France"),
  year = c("2018","2018","2018","2018","2019","2019","2019","2019","2018","2018","2018","2018","2019","2019","2019","2019"),
  type = c("profit", "revenue","profit", "revenue","profit", "revenue","profit", "revenue","profit", "revenue","profit", "revenue","profit", "revenue","profit", "revenue"),
  value = c(10,20,30,40,20,30,40,50,140,150,120,130,100,110,80,90)
)
```

Output:

```
   comp_name country year    type value
1          A      US 2018  profit    10
2          A      US 2018 revenue    20
3          B      US 2018  profit    30
4          B      US 2018 revenue    40
5          A      US 2019  profit    20
6          A      US 2019 revenue    30
7          B      US 2019  profit    40
8          B      US 2019 revenue    50
9          C  France 2018  profit   140
10         C  France 2018 revenue   150
11         D  France 2018  profit   120
12         D  France 2018 revenue   130
13         C  France 2019  profit   100
14         C  France 2019 revenue   110
15         D  France 2019  profit    80
16         D  France 2019 revenue    90
```

I want to add a row for each country which calculates the sum of all profits in that country for 2019, like this:

```
   comp_name country year                 type value
1          A      US 2018               profit    10
2          A      US 2018              revenue    20
3          B      US 2018               profit    30
4          B      US 2018              revenue    40
5          A      US 2019               profit    20
6          A      US 2019              revenue    30
7          B      US 2019               profit    40
8          B      US 2019              revenue    50
9          C  France 2018               profit   140
10         C  France 2018              revenue   150
11         D  France 2018               profit   120
12         D  France 2018              revenue   130
13         C  France 2019               profit   100
14         C  France 2019              revenue   110
15         D  France 2019               profit    80
16         D  France 2019              revenue    90
17      <NA>      US 2019 total_country_profit    60
18      <NA>  France 2019 total_country_profit   180
```

So row 17 shows the sum of the profit of the two companies operating in the US in 2019. And likewise, row 18 does the same for France.

My actual data set has several companies and countries so I need a script that can automate this process.

I'm new to R and am yet to become totally familiar with functions. Any help would be gladly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

taking `df` prior to other syntax, won't impact your output order

```
df %>%
  bind_rows(df %>% group_by(country) %>%
              summarise(value = sum(value[year == '2019' & type == 'profit']),
                        year = '2019',
                        type = 'total_profit'))

   comp_name country year         type value
1          A      US 2018       profit    10
2          A      US 2018      revenue    20
3          B      US 2018       profit    30
4          B      US 2018      revenue    40
5          A      US 2019       profit    20
6          A      US 2019      revenue    30
7          B      US 2019       profit    40
8          B      US 2019      revenue    50
9          C  France 2018       profit   140
10         C  France 2018      revenue   150
11         D  France 2018       profit   120
12         D  France 2018      revenue   130
13         C  France 2019       profit   100
14         C  France 2019      revenue   110
15         D  France 2019       profit    80
16         D  France 2019      revenue    90
17      <NA>  France 2019 total_profit   180
18      <NA>      US 2019 total_profit    60
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use -

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_by(country) %>%
  summarise(value = sum(value[year == 2019 & type == 'profit']), 
            type = 'total_country_profit', 
            year = '2019') %>%
  bind_rows(df) %>%
  arrange(comp_name)

#   country value type                 year  comp_name
#   <chr>   <dbl> <chr>                <chr> <chr>    
# 1 US         10 profit               2018  A        
# 2 US         20 revenue              2018  A        
# 3 US         20 profit               2019  A        
# 4 US         30 revenue              2019  A        
# 5 US         30 profit               2018  B        
# 6 US         40 revenue              2018  B        
# 7 US         40 profit               2019  B        
# 8 US         50 revenue              2019  B        
# 9 France    140 profit               2018  C        
#10 France    150 revenue              2018  C        
#11 France    100 profit               2019  C        
#12 France    110 revenue              2019  C        
#13 France    120 profit               2018  D        
#14 France    130 revenue              2018  D        
#15 France     80 profit               2019  D        
#16 France     90 revenue              2019  D        
#17 France    180 total_country_profit 2019  NA       
#18 US         60 total_country_profit 2019  NA
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for, thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You can also use the `add_row` function from package `tibble` for your purpose:

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
library(tibble)

DF %>%
  group_split(country) %>%
  map_dfr(~ add_row(.x, country = first(.x$country), year = "2019", 
                    type = "Total_Country_Profit", value = sum(.x$value[.x$type == "profit" & .x$year == "2019"])))

# A tibble: 18 x 5
   comp_name country year  type                 value
   <chr>     <chr>   <chr> <chr>                <dbl>
 1 C         France  2018  profit                 140
 2 C         France  2018  revenue                150
 3 D         France  2018  profit                 120
 4 D         France  2018  revenue                130
 5 C         France  2019  profit                 100
 6 C         France  2019  revenue                110
 7 D         France  2019  profit                  80
 8 D         France  2019  revenue                 90
 9 NA        France  2019  Total_Country_Profit   180
10 A         US      2018  profit                  10
11 A         US      2018  revenue                 20
12 B         US      2018  profit                  30
13 B         US      2018  revenue                 40
14 A         US      2019  profit                  20
15 A         US      2019  revenue                 30
16 B         US      2019  profit                  40
17 B         US      2019  revenue                 50
18 NA        US      2019  Total_Country_Profit    60
```